# How to bind arguments to child function in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In React it's common to bind parameters for child components like so:

```html
<Child onChange={e =>
  doThing(complex.variable.inParentScope[3], e.target.value)} foo="bar" />
```

I want to do similarly in Vue, in order to keep the child components as dumb as possible (it should just have to call `onClick={(e) => onChange(e)}`. However, I read passing a function as a prop is generally an antipattern in Vue, and I can't figure how I should bind the arguments from the parent in order to keep the code reusable. I want to do something like:

```js
[1,2,3,4,5,dataFromAPI].map(data =>
  <Child change="e => handleChange(data, foo, e.target.value) />
```

How is this achieved?

Comment: The child emits a change event, the parent listens for it and runs the parent function:  https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Method-Event-Handlers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with passing a function to a child, IMHO. The reason why it's not a pattern you see often in Vue is because Vue offers `$emit()`. Here's an example:

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.component('child', {
  template: `<input @change="$emit('some-event', $event.target.value)" />`,
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    myList: [1, 2, 3]
  }),
  methods: {
    someFn(item, index, value) {
      console.log({item, index, value});
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.12/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <child v-for="(item, index) in myList"
         :key="index"
         @some-event="someFn(item, index, $event)" />
</div>
```

The child component is kept as dumb as possible (it doesn't know it's part of a list, it doesn't know its `index` and it doesn't know what the parent component does with its `value` once it emits). All it needs to know is its own value and when it has to `$emit()` it.

Note `$emit()` doesn't bubble. If you need far-reaching alternatives, consider dispatching/committing to a store or using event bus.

Comment: But in the parent, I need to dynamically assign arguments to the child (i.e. it's rendered from a list). How can I do that? Something like `[1,2,3].map(n => <child @some-event="e => someFn(n, foo, e) />`

Comment: Don't pass the list data or the callback to the child component. Just have the child emit its own data and, when it  does, couple it with the data in the list and call the callback function. Basically the child doesn't need to know anything about what happens once it emits. And you have everything else in the parent.

Comment: Here I think he's asking about `v-for`

Comment: @ahota, I just updated the example with how you can combine arguments from both parent and child.

Comment: But the goal is to try to keep the child component as dumb as possible. When it emits its event, it actually needs to emit a combination of several variables, and I don't want the child component to know/care about that, otherwise it's moving some of the parent logic into the child.

Comment: @tao sorry, I did not see your comment/updated example. Thanks for updating your answer!